# Python Pandas error "ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'list'>"

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito añadir en un dataframe, los datos de otros dataframes, utilizando la función merge, para conseguir que solamente tome a quellos valores cuyos índices tienen la misma fecha.
La sentencia que muestro a continuación, me devuelve el error mencionado en el Título.

```
df_total = pd.merge(cotiz_diaria, [df, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12], left_index=True, right_index=True) 
df_df_total
```

El error parece indicar que no admite listas de df.

¿De qué otra manera podría realizar esta unión, que no sea añadiendo cada dataframe uno a uno ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente tú diagnóstico es el adecuado. Lo que ocurre es que [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) no acepta una lista de `Dataframe` a lo sumo permite pasarle dos de estos objetos. Pero puedes iterar sobre la lista y hacer el proceso de `merge`. Por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 1, 2]]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['b', 3, 4]]))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['c', 5, 6]]))

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
```

Hemos creado una lista `dfs` que contiene 3  `DataFrame`, ahora podemos hacer el 
`merge`:

```
dfs = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs)
for df_ in dfs:
    df_final = df_final.merge(df_, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df_final)

  0_x 1_x 2_x 0_y 1_y 2_y  0  1  2
0   a   1   2   b   3   4  c  5  6
```

Detalle:

- Con `dfs = iter(dfs)` convertimos la lista en un `iterador`, esto por la forma en que vamos a procesar, al necesitar por un lado el primer elemento y luego el resto, es preferible hacerlo así y evitar hacer copias de listas.
- Con `df_final = next(dfs)`  inicializamos el `DataFrame` final con el primer objeto de la lista
- Luego simplemente iteramos sobre los siguientes elementos de la lista y con `df_final = df_final.merge(df_, left_index=True, right_index=True)` vamos haciendo el `merge` de cada objeto.

Un resultado idéntico pero con menos líneas de código es usar la función [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.reduce)

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs)
print(df_final)
```

Comment: Nunca es tarde para agradecer una respuesta tan pedagógica. Gracias